# How to map key '§' to '<' in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I have OS X running in my VM and I would like to remap the key '§' to '<'.
I installed already "Karabiner", which gives thousand of options, but I didn't manage to simply achieve this.

Any help on how to to map this key ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) app to achieve a similar goal. It's a bit complicated though.

Comment: I guess that will be the solution for me. I didn't practically test it, but I saw from a youtube video, that it does what I like. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I am missing a key in ukulele. Means when pressing the physical key it does not show up in the blue keys of ukulele. Is there a way to add missing keys ? I am missing the red marked key in ukulele.

Comment: Not sure, I haven't encountered that myself. Ukulele shows me a fully blue keyboard, and when I press anything the key I've pressed gets highlighted in green. Maybe try creating a layout based on an existing layout that already has your missing key, maybe then you'll be able to re-map it...